# Creating and "Scheduling" pthreads with executable applications

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want to create a "Scheduler" that creates threads (pthreads),
each pthread will run an executale file,
and I want to control the scheduling via the Scheduler.

The only change I want to do in the applications is the add some lines of "waiting" code,
and I want the scheduler to be able to wake them.

---

The way the execute the applications as I know is to use "execve" in each pthread,
but in this way, the applications will not preserved the previous DATA segment, so I can't control them via Conditions Variables.

---

What is a good way to to that?

Thanks!

Comment: Pre-emptive schedule or not? Can't you do this better with a simple script and `nice`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

You can control your child processes using `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` signals.

Threads are completely irrelevant.